# Mongo DB Remove Field in Array inside an Array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, server, backend

I have following structure of my document:

```
{
    "daily": [
        {
            "general": [
                {
                    "status": false,
                    "_id": "5e728265f4796c0017203662",
                    "title": "Sport"
                },...
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to pull the the document inside the "general" Array by it's "_id".

I tried several things but nothing seems to work for me.

Every help will be appreciate :)

Comment: Can you post your code which you have tried so far?

Comment: what should be the response ?

Comment: Generate ObjectId first then it will be easy to update

Comment: I don't want to have a repsonse. I just want to remove the embedded document inside of the "general" array @Kun

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The update query to pull the sub-document from the nested array field `general` using the `_id`:

```
ID = "5e728265f4796c0017203662"

db.collection.update(
 { "daily.general._id": ID },
 { $pull: { "daily.$.general": { _id: ID } } }
)
```

Comment: Field `_id` is typically an `ObjectId`, so I assume it should be rather `ID = ObjectId("5e728265f4796c0017203662")`

Answer (score 0):

This can only be done in Mongo 4.2+,  where they introduced [pipeline'd updates](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/).

Now we can use aggregation expressions to update documents:

```
db.collection.updateOne(
    {},
    [
        {
            $set: {
                "daily": {
                    $map: {
                        input: "$daily",
                        as: "item",
                        in: {
                            "general": {
                                $filter: {
                                    input: "$$item.general",
                                    as: "datum",
                                    cond: {$ne: ["$$datum._id", "5e728265f4796c0017203662"]}
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]);
```

Or if objects in daily have more than just the general field you can do it like this:

```
db.collection.updateOne(
    {},
    [
        {
            $set: {
                "daily": {
                    $map: {
                        input: "$daily",
                        as: "item",
                        in: {
                            $mergeObjects: [
                                "$$item",
                                {
                                    "general": {
                                        $filter: {
                                            input: "$$item.general",
                                            as: "datum",
                                            cond: {$ne: ["$$datum._id", "5e728265f4796c0017203662"]}
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]);
```

Unfortunately for any other Mongo version this is not possible, you'll have to restructure your data or do it in code.

Comment: It is possible without aggregation expression, see answer above (which is even much shorter).

Comment: No it's not, since when is the length of an answer an indicator if its correct or not? feel free to use the "short" answer. i have a feeling it won't work.

Comment: The code from prasad_ is much shorter. Your code is working correctly but your statement "This can only be done in Mongo 4.2+, where they introduced pipeline'd updates." is wrong. `$[<identifier>]` was introduced in Mongo 3.6